# Changing the publishing source of a single repository in github pages

Tags: github-pages

I have created a repo in github and it has 2 branches: the master branch and a sub-branch. I uploaded a folder containing the files for  my website in the sub-branch. In the settings , in the github pages'tab I have been given two options for publishing the source code of my repository:

master branch
Use the master branch for GitHub Pages.

master branch /docs folder
Use only the /docs folder for GitHub Pages.

I did not find the option of creating gh-pages.

I have chosen the first option "master branch". The problem is that when clicking on the link of the github site I do not see the files of my website but instead,I read what is written in the master branch's README.MD file which is only the title of my repository. I want to change that .I wish the files of my folder be displayed starting by the file of the main web page.
So my question is how I can change the publishing source of my repository in order for my folder's files be displayed? Is it possible to do that?
Thank you.
I am sorry I have found the way of uploading the screenshots for better explaining my problem in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `index.html` file at the root of the `master` branch. Then it should work.